# Traits conflict resolution together with changing visibility

Tags: php, traits, php-7

Let's assume we have 2 traits (tested in PHP 7.1):

```
<?php

trait HelloA
{
    private function X()
    {
        echo "x";
    }
}

trait HelloB
{
    private function X()
    {
        echo "y";
    }
}
```

if we want to apply any of traits and make method X public we can define class like this:

```
class Summary
{
    use HelloA {
        HelloA::X as public;
    }
}
```

and then we can use without any problem

```
$s = new Summary();
$s->X();
```

and it works without any problem.

But if we want to use both traits and have Summary class defined like so:

```
class Summary
{
    use HelloA, HelloB {
        HelloA::X as public;
    }
}
```

we will get Fatal error:

> Trait method X has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on Summary.

We can solve the conflict defining class like this:

```
class Summary
{
    use HelloA, HelloB {
        HelloA::X insteadof HelloB;
    }
}
```

but now it's impossible to run

```
$s = new Summary();
$s->X();
```

any more, because we would get Fatal Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to private method Summary::X() from context ''

The question is - is there any way to do in Summary class both conflict resolution and also changing method visibility?

At the moment I think it's not possible, construction like this for example:

```
use HelloA, HelloB {
        HelloA::X insteadof HelloB as public;
    }
```

would cause Parse error but maybe it should be written in some other way to make it work?

Obviously as workaround we could create in Summary class with different method name and run `X` method inside it but it's not what I'm asking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can change both the method visibility and do conflict resolution, just not in the same statement.

```
class Summary
{
    use HelloA, HelloB {
        HelloA::X insteadof HelloB;
        HelloA::X as public;
    }
}
```

This should give you exactly what you expect.

Comment: Thanks it seems to work. I was trying this too but must have used `HelloB::X as public;` and then I was getting Fatal error